# Não consigo trazer os dados do array que esta mostrando no console

Tags: react

```
import React from "react";

function TrackingResult({ data }) {
  if (!data || !data.length) return null;

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Tracking Result</h1>
      <ul className="list-group">
        {data.map(item => {
          const { data, origem, destino, status } = item;
          console.log(item.evento)
          return (
            <li key="{index}" className="list-group-item">
              <span className="badge badge-primary">{origem}</span>
              <span>data: {data}</span>
              <span>destino: {destino}</span>
              <span>status: {status}</span>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default TrackingResult;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o `data` é um `array` ou um `object`

Answer (score 1):

Provável que você esteja usando o map de maneira errada ou eu desconheço essa maneira descrita aí...
Eu usaria da seguinte forma

```
{data.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <li key={index} className="list-group-item">
      <span className="badge badge-primary">{item.origem}</span>
      <span>data: {item.data}</span>
      <span>destino: {item.destino}</span>
      <span>status: {item.status}</span>
    </li>
  );
})}
```

Por precaução, adicionaria um useEffect para renderizar sua tela novamente caso o data mude

Comment: Tem que ver com o que está perguntando se é um `array` ou é um `objeto`!

Comment: Vrdd, tem isso.